# I can't view the source code of my Cloud Function from Google Cloud Console( Firebase using)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-console

As I am owner of the project, last week I could view the source code via Google Cloud Console but now I can't view it like attached files.

Please, let me know what I should do.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to re-login or use browser incognito mode.

Comment: Please, give it a try the steps mentioned by @JohnMichaelG as this seems to be a local issue, as it's not possible to reproduce it.

Comment: I have the same problem, tried to login again and use incognito the same problem !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is funny, but it could be related to billing problems.

E.g. in my case, it wast 0.4 USD ‍♂️